# Will my experience be compromised using AirPods Pro with Bluetooth 4 only hardware?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, airpods

I have a MacBook Air 2014 with Bluetooth 4.0 and I’m considering to buy AirPods Pro. I assume that it makes sense to promote an accessory with the *lowest* standard they're compatible with, and AirPods Pro are promoted with Bluetooth 5.I can’t find answers to things like does Stereo sound or Spatial Audio require 5.0. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPods_Pro)  only mentions iOS devices.

Will a macOS 4.0 device compromise AirPods features in any direct way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, AirPods Pro will work with a MacBook Air 2014 and provide stereo sound. You will not, however, enjoy Spatial Audio, that is reserved for iOS devices only. See [this support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211775) for specific requirements regarding spatial audio.

Comment: I didn't doubt that they "work". But to what extent? Stereo? They're promoted with Bluetooth 5. I guess it would make sense to promote them with the *lowest* Bluetooth standard they're compatble with; so, am I missing out on something when I can only offer Bluetooth 4?